# Linked list not accepting new nodes when called in a loop

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, runtime-error, singly-linked-list

**The problem with the code is that I cant assign new nodes without affecting previously assigned nodes while using switch. It keeps reassigning with the latest given node inputs**

***linked list structure node*** the structure for linked list is assigned as follows

```
typedef struct stringData {
char *s;
struct stringData *next;
} Node;
```

***create insert and print linked list*** Below is the code for creating and printing linked list

```
Node *createNode(char *s) {
Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->s = s;
newNode->next = NULL;
return newNode;
}

void insert(Node **link, Node *newNode) {
newNode->next = *link;
*link = newNode;
}

void printList(Node *head) {
while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", head->s);
    head = head->next;
}
}
```

***main*** *when am compiling I cant assign linked list in run time ,that is when I have to assign the more than one node  while in switch .How can I remove this mistake?*

```
Node *head = NULL;
Node *tail = NULL;
Node *n;

char message_arr[10] = {};
int choice =0;  
int len;
char str[20];

n = createNode("Hi");
insert(&head, n);
tail = n;
        
        
n = createNode("Hello");
insert(&tail->next, n);
tail = n;
       
        
        
        
n = createNode("How are you");
insert(&tail->next, n);
tail = n;
int index,ind;       
        
        
 while(choice!=6)       
 
 {
 printf("\nChoose one option from the list\n");  
    printf("\n 1. New Message  2. Display all messages  3.Delete all messages\n");  
    printf("\nEnter your choice?\n");         
    scanf("\n%d",&choice);  
    switch(choice)  
    {  
        case 1:  
        printf("\nEnter new message\n");
        scanf("%s",message_arr);
        
        n = createNode(message_arr);
        insert(&tail->next, n);
        tail = n;
        break;  
          
        case 2:  
        printf("\nMessages so far:\n\n");
        printList(head);     
        break;  
        
        case 3:
        printf("\nDeleting all messages.....\n");
        free_list(head);
         printf("\nMessages deleted.....\n");
        break;
        case 6:
        exit(0); 
        
        break;  
        default:  
        printf("Please enter valid choice."); 
        
        
          
    }  
    
    
 }
return(0);
```

**Output**
Choose one option from the list 1. New Message  2. Read a Message  3.
Display all messages  4. Delete a message 5.Delete all messages

```
Enter your choice?
1

Enter new message
morning


Choose one option from the list 1. New Message  2. Read a Message  3. 
Display all messages  4. Delete a message 5.Delete all messages

Enter your choice?
1

Enter new message
giya

Choose one option from the list

1. New Message  2. Read a Message  3. Display all messages  4. Delete a 
message 5.Delete all messages

Enter your choice?
3

Messages so far:

Hi
Hello
How are you
giya
giya
```

when I'am calling the switch's first case to enter "new message " twice, then the first message already assigned is also replaced by the second one and is displayed twice as `giya` `giya`

Comment: Note that every node will point to the same string, so the data will be the most recent entry. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be copy/pasted and compiled. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "*when am compiling I cant assign linked list in run time*". What does that mean? Why "can't"? Is there an error or incorrect behaviour? Please give the exact input, expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: `scanf("\n%d",&choice);` ==> `scanf("%d",&choice);` and always *check what value* is returned by `scanf`. That is the number of conversions made. Also, you are not restricting the length of string entered into `char message_arr[10]` which is max 9, so you can have an easy buffer overflow.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're asking about their differences.

Comment: I have updated my output as well can you check @kaylum

Comment: If you want to be able to create items in a loop, then you will have to use **allocated memory** (`malloc`) to store the strings. This is the most common way to allow each new string to have its own memory without erasing the previous ones. But that also means that you will have to free it, and that you cannot directly use litteral strings in your nodes, but copy them to allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

*> when I'am calling the switch's first case to enter "new message " twice, then the first message already assigned is also replaced by the second one and is displayed twice as `giya` `giya`*

The reason is that all your newly created nodes `s` member pointer is pointing to same buffer `message_arr`. That's why, when displaying them, all of them print the current content of `message_arr` buffer, which is the last value you have entered.

To understand it better:

First you have entered value `morning` for newly created node in list:

```
     ---------
 --->|   |   |-->NULL     
     ---------            
       |
       |                   message_arr
       |                  ---------------------
       |_________________>|m|o|r|n|i|n|g| | | |
                          ---------------------
```

then you have entered value `giya` for newly created node in list:

```
     ---------   ---------
 --->|   |   |-->|   |   |--->NULL  
     ---------   ---------         
       |           |
       |           |        message_arr
       |           |----> ---------------------
       |----------------->|g|i|y|a| | | | | | |
                          ---------------------
```

To solve this problem, after creating new node, you should allocate memory to `s` pointer member of `Node` structure and copy the content of `message_arr` buffer to the allocated memory. Alternatively, you can use `strdup()` to resolve this issue:

```
Node *createNode(char *s) {
Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->s = strdup(s);    // <----------
```

The [strdup()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string passed to it. `strdup()` allocates memory for the new string and returns its pointer. Make sure to free it using `free()` once you are done with it. Note that `strdup()` is not part of the C Standard.

Since, you have added both the `C` and `C++` tag to your question, an important point for this way of initialisation:

```
char message_arr[10] = {};
```

Empty initialisers is as per `C++` standard but are non-conforming in `C`, though some `C` compilers accept it.

In `C`, you should do:

```
char message_arr[10] = {0};
```

which is acceptable in `C++` as well.

Follow good programming practice, make sure to check return value of `malloc()`, `scanf()` etc. Also, make sure to check whether the user input for `choice` is valid or not. You should check, what happens when user give input as some character instead of number for `choice` prompt!